# How to mask a portion of a stroked path in SVG?

Tags: svg, mask

I'm looking to mask a portion of a straight line in SVG and can really only figure out how to do it one way, but would rather do another because the line lengths will be dynamically generated and the mask portion won't.

Let me explain.

Assume I have a line that is `<path d="M0,0 L0,100" stroke="blue" stroke-width="20"/>`, I would like to mask with transparency the first 10 pixels, meaning just the `d="M0,0 L0,10"` portion.

I can do this, which produces the results I'd like:

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect stroke="black" stroke-width="2" width="100" height="100" fill="yellow"/>
  <svg x="10" y="0" width="200" height="200"  >
    <defs>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="10" stroke="none"/>
      <mask id="chopmask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect width="20" height="90" x="0" y="10" fill="white"/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <path d="M0,0 L0,100" mask="url(#chopmask)" stroke="blue" stroke-width="20"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

But the issue is that I can't seem to do the opposite with the `rect` in the `mask`, wherein I simply define the it as `<rect width="20" height="10" x="0" y="0" fill="white"/>` (notice only `height` and `y` are different).

Am I missing something on how do define a 10x20 rectangle and have it's mask simply hide a portion of a stroked path, or is this impossible?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, then you need to have a mask in the form of a rectangle of fixed size 10Х20, which will be applied to the line with variable length.

In this case, you can try on a combined mask, one part of which will be opaque `fill = "black"` and the second part will be transparent `fill = "white"` and show the rest of the line.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect stroke="black" stroke-width="2" width="100" height="100" fill="yellow"/>
  <svg x="10" y="0" width="200" height="200"  >
    <defs>
       <mask id="chopmask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <rect width="20" height="100" x="0" y="0" fill="white"/>
         <rect width="20" height="10" x="0" y="0" fill="black"/>
     </mask>
    </defs>
       <path d="M0,0 L0,100" mask="url(#chopmask)" stroke="blue" stroke-width="20"/>
  </svg> 
</svg>
```

An example of animating the line masking process with a rectangle `10 x 20px`

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect stroke="black" stroke-width="2" width="100" height="100" fill="yellow"/>
  <svg x="10" y="0" width="200" height="200"  >
    <defs>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="10" stroke="none"/>
      <mask id="chopmask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <rect width="20" height="100" x="0" y="0" fill="white"/>
         <rect width="20" height="10" x="0" y="0" fill="black">
      <animate attributeName="y" dur="2s" values="-10;0" fill="freeze" />
    </rect> 
     </mask>
    </defs>
       <path d="M0,0 L0,100" mask="url(#chopmask)" stroke="blue" stroke-width="20"/>
  </svg> 
</svg>
```

Comment: @Todd Main If I misunderstood your question, please write it in the comments.

Comment: Thanks sir. I think the problem is with the first rect. My paths will be variable length and so I'm looking for a solution that is generalized for any length without sending that in

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir I can not clearly understand what you want to get in the end. Maybe it's better to draw a picture? Words are understood by different people in different ways.

Comment: the issue is that in the mask, `<rect width="20" height="100" x="0" y="0" fill="white"/>` defines the length of the line. I'm looking to do that without defining the length. Maybe it's not a line, maybe it's an arc or a Bezier.

Comment: @ToddMain I agree in the mask can be any basic figure svg and that it determines the size of the mask action

Answer (score 1):

Works for me ... am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect stroke="black" stroke-width="2" width="100" height="100" fill="yellow"/>
  <svg x="10" y="0" width="200" height="200"  >
    <defs>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="10" stroke="none"/>
      <mask id="chopmask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect width="20" height="10" x="0" y="0" fill="white"/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <path d="M0,0 L0,100" mask="url(#chopmask)" stroke="blue" stroke-width="20"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. It looks promising

Comment: Actually, this has the opposite effect of what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think you're looking for a clip-path, not a mask?